# How to restore JPDA settings for glassfish 4.0 through cmd

Tags: java, glassfish

To enable debug mode on glassfish 4.0, I've changed the 'debug options' on 'jvm settings' but when I tried to start my domain using 'start-domain' it is getting an error:

```
the server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:
Java Hotspot(TM) 64 bit server vm warning: ignoring options  MaxPermsize=192m, supported was removed in 80
ERROR: JDWP option syntax error: -agentlib:  jdwp=transport=dt_Socket,Server=y,Suspend=n,address=9009
command start-domain failed
```

How to reset those settings through cmd?